# "Price Impact Too High" swapping tokens back to ETH on basic contract with liquidity (Uniswap)

Tags: tokens, ether, uniswap, swaps, liquidity-provider

I created [this basic smart contract](https://rinkeby.etherscan.io/address/0xeb163cb41bd476fb53b327cfb48a13d55a1a1b72) on Rinkeby (uses OpenZeppelin `ERC20PresetMinterPauser` preset), [minted 1m FOO](https://rinkeby.etherscan.io/tx/0x698417d21569a85fb883039ad361dac0bbf4c849d54a61c15b268cdb379066a8), then [added liquidity](https://rinkeby.etherscan.io/tx/0x92e74d7242ca618d85f263ae85802c8e7bb0db2a3a71481d5338cd435ffc7e54) on [Uniswap v2](https://app.uniswap.org/#/pool/v2) with 10 ETH and 1m FOO. I then [swapped](https://rinkeby.etherscan.io/tx/0x67d7c1075096ad3c8b6b9f618e8308526f6bd2b7e1f110e2889ee4eee369aba8) 1 ETH for 90,661 FOO.

However, if I try to [swap back](https://app.uniswap.org/#/swap?use=V2), it says "Price Impact Too High", no matter how little amount of FOO I specify:

[image]

In fact, the info balloon says 0% price impact, so this makes it even more odd:

[image]

Any help appreciated. Of course, I set my price slippage to 30% to make sure, but there's clearly something else going on here.

Comment: Hi, did you check the gas price or gas amount you've sending ?

Comment: @defikintaro You didn't read the question properly. This is way before that stage.

Answer (score 2):

I contacted [Uniswap support on Discord](https://discord.gg/FCfyBSbCU5), and they said it's a known issue on testnets due to them using "fake dollar prices", and it can be worked around by enabling Expert Mode, which I did, and it allowed me to 'Swap Anyway'. The issue is described in this [GitHub issue](https://github.com/Uniswap/uniswap-interface/issues/1706) - slightly different issue, but same root cause.

Answer (score 0):

I have been looking for something like what you are searching for until I found these useful links, I hope I could help you guys!

https://adaascapital.com/price-impact-too-high-uniswap-fix/

https://adaascapital.com/price-impact-too-high-pancakeswap-solution/

Regards.

Comment: Link only answer are discouraged. Please write the answer and only use the link to expand the details.